# Linking Calendars&Tasks in SharePoint 2010

Tags: web-part, outlook, sharepoint-calendar, out-of-the-box, ootb

I'm in the process of a build out a project management site for my company.

The site (and subsites) all have task lists and calendars to track initiaves.

Each calendar is already linked to a shared calendar for that specific group.

I'm looking for a OOTB way (if one exists) to link the tasks created in SharePoint to the calendars so that info appears in outlook as well as SharePoint. It would also be helpful if the solution worked in the opsite direction as well (tasks created and assigned in outlook populate the task list and calendar in SharePoint)

Comment: What did you end up doing? I want to do this too.

Comment: We ended up using just dropping the task list in Sharpoint and overlaying the shared calendar from Outlook. People now manage their tasks on from outlook and update the calendar. I've hear 2012 offers an OOTB solution for this, I'm just not sure how far off our upgrade is.